# MVC.NET: Sharing validation rules between controllers and the service (business) layer

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project where we have multiple UI (view) models with `DataAnnotations` attributes for validation, mainly for input such as required fields, length, regular expressions, etc):

```
[Required]
public int Order { get; set; }
[Required]
[MaxLength(150)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

The controller checks the ModelState to make sure objects are valid before handing them to the service layer.

Now, the service layer also validates the objects in order to accommodate for future changes that may require a new controller to support other output formats or another utility to import objects in batch.

**My question is:** Knowing that there should be a separation of concerns where controllers deal with UI models and Service layers deal with Business Objects, and therefore, I wouldn't like to pass UI model objects to the service layers, what's the preferred way to reuse the validation rules in the UI model objects? Or should they be replicated with code in the service layer? or should the `DataAnnotations` be added to the Business Objects too?

I'm using **EF model first**, so I don't see a simple way to add these annotations to the auto-generated POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use FluentValidation? That way you can create a validator for each view model and run them in your UI layer and service layer if needs be. It also removes the need to decorate your view models with validation attributes. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/